# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'push_notifications' I am getting this error after I've uninstalled the module django push notification

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[snap of error is here which I am getting while I am migrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExwQb.png)

First I've installed this package using pip install django-push-notifications 
after that I've removed this package through pip uninstall django-push-notifications after that when I've tried migrating this. I am getting this error

Comment: You have uninstalled the module, therefore Django could not find it. Thats why it's giving error. If you have uninstalled the module, please remove `push_notifications` present in INSTALLES_APPS of you settings.py file

Comment: Check, if you still have it registered in your `Installed_Apps` in `settings.py`. If so remove it.

Comment: Thanks @ReemaParakh I am still wondering how I can forget this. plzz answer this  so that I can accept.

Comment: @DiwakarYadav Posted it as a answer, please accept it.

Comment: @ans2human brother I've to accept reema prakash she commented first. Sorry brother, thanks for answering by the way

Comment: @DiwakarYadav, sure no problem. Its all about helping and having a little fun while working. So all good, go ahead and accept her answer. BTW you can still upvote mine. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have uninstalled the module, therefore Django could not find it. Thats why it's giving error.

If you have uninstalled the module, please remove `push_notifications` present in `INSTALLED_APPS` of your `settings.py` file

Answer (score 0):

Check, if you still have it registered in your `Installed_Apps` in `settings.py`. If so remove it.

If its not in the `installed_apps` then check your URLCONF --> `project/urls.py` if there's any url related to it.